# QTreeView multiple column, possible?

Tags: qt4, qtreeview, qt4.7

I'm using `QStandardItemModel` with a `QTreeView`, I wanted the left pane to show the nodes, and the right pane to show value of the node, which is column 0 and column 1 in this case.

Construction of nodes was pretty successful, but when I'm trying to place values into that model with  `QStandardItem::insertRow(1, XX)`, the item wasn't showing up at all, is there something I missed?

@update:

Since i recursively create nodes , i use:

```
void Widget::addNode(QStandardItem *parent, const QVariant & data)
{
     QStandardItem *childKey = ...; // left pane
     QStandardItem *childValue = ...; // right pane

     parent->appendRow (childKey);

}
```

I can't just use `model.setItem()` to append `childValue` , since it went to the wrong row , and QTreeView is not expanded by default, when new node is appended.

Comment: For an example in Python: http://neurochannels.blogspot.com/2015/02/pyside-tree-model-vi-building-trees.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your code to make sure that you have told the model how many columns that you want, i.e. that you have called [QStandardItemModel::setColumnCount()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setColumnCount), to tell the model about the extra columns.

**Edit**

Then you need to set the value of each item in each column. One way to do this is to use 
[`QStandardItemModel::setItem ( int row, int column, QStandardItem * item`)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItem)

> Sets the item for the given row and column to item. The model takes ownership of the item. If necessary, the row count and column count are increased to fit the item. The previous item at the given location (if there was one) is deleted.

Comment: Applied , but still one problem left , it's always inserting rows to column 0 , how can i specify the column ..

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple columns at once to a parent for the same child node like this:

```
void Widget::addNode(QStandardItem *parent, const QVariant & data)
{
     QStandardItem *childKey = ...; // left pane
     QStandardItem *childValue = ...; // right pane

     QList<QStandardItem*> childColumns;
     childColumns<< childKey << childValue;

     parent->appendRow(childColumns);

}
```